# How to fix "Tensor had NaN values" while training in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tpu

While training an object detector on a Cloud TPU I get the following error:

`Error recorded from training_loop: Gradient for FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_48/weights:0 is NaN : Tensor had NaN values`

This always happens at the same step in my training. I'm quite unsure what I might be doing wrong to cause this.

Any advice would be great! I'll try to respond as quickly as possible.

I've followed [this guide](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193)  to train the object detector on Google's TPU systems.

Here's the full error:
`Error recorded from training_loop: Gradient for FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_48/weights:0 is NaN : Tensor had NaN values [[node CheckNumerics_99 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1112) ]] Caused by op u'CheckNumerics_99', defined at: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/model_tpu_main.py", line 142, in <module> tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run _sys.exit(main(argv)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/model_tpu_main.py", line 126, in main estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=train_steps) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2452, in train saving_listeners=saving_listeners) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 358, in train loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1124, in _train_model return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1154, in _train_model_default features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2251, in _call_model_fn config) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1112, in _call_model_fn model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2633, in _model_fn update_ops = _sync_variables_ops(ctx) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 207, in _sync_variables_ops for v in variables.trainable_variables() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 919, in check_numerics "CheckNumerics", tensor=tensor, message=message, name=name) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper op_def=op_def) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op op_def=op_def) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in __init__ self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack() InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Gradient for FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_48/weights:0 is NaN : Tensor had NaN values [[node CheckNumerics_99 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1112) ]]
Expand all | Collapse all {`

Comment: What are possible steps I can take?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow doesn't play nice with NaN values. I would recommend using SciKit Learns built in Imputer function to "Fill in the missing data"

```
# Import Important Modules
import numpy as np # Numpy for Linear Algebra
import pandas as pd # Pandas for data storage and representation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Matplotlib for glorious charts

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

## THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO IMPORT DUDE!

```
dataset = dataset 
# This is a pretend variable. I don't know what the specifics of your 
# dataset are

# Imputer has 2 "Strategies" you might find useful
# Mean (replacing the missing values in your dataset 
# with the mean of all values in that column)

# Most Frequent (Replacing the missing values in your 
# dataset with the most frequent value "I.E MODE" )

mean_imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
# missing values parameter is what SimpleImputer is looking to 
# "Fill" in the dataset
# strategy is the type of imputing SimpleImputer is going to perform. 
# In this case, replace missing values with the mean of that column

most_frequent_imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')

### FIT THE IMPUTER TO YOUR DATASET:
# Note: One thing I didn't know for the longest time is that the 
# methods I thought separate

# mean_imputer.fit() & mean_imputer.transform() can actually be 
# performed in one action
# mean_imputer.fit_transform() :-)!

dataset = mean_imputer.fit_transform(dataset) 
# Apply the mean imputer to the dataset

dataset = most_frequent_imputer.fit_transform(dataset) 
# Apply the most frequent imputer to the dataset

### I hope this helps. 
### If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.
```